# Iscroll and jquery mobile problems

Tags: ios, jquery-mobile, iscroll4

I'm not very great at javascript and i am having trouble mixing iscroll and jquery mobile. I am testing it on IOS

This is what I have;

http://m.filmrev.me

Both pages are scrolling but not in the correct way.

Would anybody be able to help with this.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

check this link

http://cubiq.org/dropbox/iscroll4/examples/simple/

And

yours  example there are 2 same id  for div and 'ul' .
try it change these ids.

ex..

in page,    `<div id='scroller '>`

in page 2 ,

```
<div id='scroller''>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the jQuery Mobile iscroll implementation - see [here](https://github.com/watusi/jquery-mobile-iscrollview). This was done specifically for JQM.

However, the JQM devs have started their own scroller, called [Overthrow](http://filamentgroup.github.com/Overthrow/). This is supposed to be more cross-platfrom compared to iscroll. I've used iscroll, scrollview (previous JQM scroller) and am now using Overthrow. Works ok and I found it fairly easy to implement.

Comment: Cool. Then please check as answer!